# ElasticSearch rollover index based on field

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, apache-kafka-connect

I'm a baby sitter learning Elastic Search. Here I'm pushing data from `Kafka` to `ES` using `Kafka Connect`. The data index size just grows and grows to TB's and its not easy to perform a search until I realized to have a new index hourly/daily, picking the date from the `Document`.

My document looks like:

```
{  
   "base":{  
      "message":"",
      "timestamp":"2019-08-09T13:20:11.877Z",
      "type":"vpc"
   },
   "ecs":{  
      "version":"1.0.0"
   }
}
```

Now could I use the timestamp and type from the document to form a new index like 'vpc-2019.08.09-1'? That helps me create and direct documents to the index based on type and timestamp.

Taking a sample, we have an alias 'foo' which is defined as a time based alias with index format as foo-yyyy.mm.dd

We get a document at Jan 10, 2018 to write to the index. The ES client infers the index to be written to is foo-2018.01.10 and writes the data to the specified index or creates it if required.
We get another document at Jan 11, 2018 to write. Index inferred will be foo-2018.01.11 and written.

I came across [this](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-can-i-name-curator-rollover-new-index-like-date-prefix-yyyy-mm-dd-1/128542), based on system time. Doesn't help.
Any suggestions?

Comment: this article might be helpful https://www.elastic.co/blog/managing-time-based-indices-efficiently

Comment: But why do you want to look inside the document for the timestamp? Isn't the timestamp the same as current date/time?

Comment: @AndreiStefan Thanks for asking. I collect logs from various systems. That said, I would like to put them in the respective generated date index instead of processed date index.